# Relatively closed subset of compact set is compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $F$ a subset of $K$ which is relatively closed in $K$. Then is $F$ a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: You might be interested in the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229868/is-a-closed-subset-of-a-compact-set-which-is-a-subset-of-a-metric-space-m-co).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $F$ in $\Bbb R^n$, and let $\mathscr{V}=\mathscr{U}\cup\{\Bbb R^n\setminus F\}$. Show that $\mathscr{V}$ is an open cover of $K$. Since $K$ is compact, $\mathscr{V}$ has a finite subcover $\mathscr{V}_0$. Conclude by showing that $\mathscr{V}_0\cap\mathscr{U}$ is a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ covering $F$.