# How do I prove that a closed subset of a compact set is compact directly from the definition?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove that a closed subset of a compact set is compact directly from the definition but I'm not sure how to proceed.

This is what I have so far:
Let $K$ be a compact set and let $A$ be a closed subset of $K$.
As $A$ is a closed set, any convergent sequence in $A$ must converge to a limit point in $A$
Let $a_n$ be a sequence in $A$. If I prove that it has a convergent subsequence, I am done

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, a hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Well isn't $(a_n)$ a sequence in $K$ too ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a closed subset of a compact set (which is a subset of a metric space $M$) compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229868/is-a-closed-subset-of-a-compact-set-which-is-a-subset-of-a-metric-space-m-co) (From your attempt, it seems your definition of compactness is actually _sequential compactness_)

Comment: Yes I just realized, if I'm not mistaken equivalence is only in a metric space, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence in $A$ is also a sequence in $K$ hence it has a convergent subsequence . The limit of this  subsequence is in $A$ because $A$ is closed